# drop rows programmatically based on contents of list column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a list column, `v2`.

[image]

The data source has some issues I don't reproduce here. To get around this problem (not shown), I'd like to drop rows in `df` with more than 4 variables in the list column `v2`.

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                     v2 = list(
                       structure(
                         list(
                           v3 = c(1:4),
                           v4 = c(1:4), 
                           v5 = c(1:4), 
                           v6 = c(NA, "", NA, "")), 
                         class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:4),
                       structure(
                         list(
                           v3 = c(1:2),
                           v4 = c(1:2), 
                           v5 = c(1:2),
                           v6 = c(1:2),
                           v7 = c(NA, "")),
                         class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
                       structure(
                         list(
                           v3 = c(1:2),
                           v4 = c(1:2), 
                           v6 = c(NA, "")),
                         class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)), 
                     v8 = c(1:3)), 
                row.names = c(NA, 3L), 
                class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You could try `df[sapply(df$v2, length) < 5,]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lengths` function to get  list length and subset based on condition

```
df[lengths(df$v2) < 5, ]

#  v1                                           v2 v8
#1  a 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA, , NA,   1
#3  c                               1, 2, 1, 2, NA,   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone looking to use `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(map_lgl(v2, ~ncol(.) < 5))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  v1    v2                      v8
  <chr> <list>               <int>
1 a     <data.frame [4 x 4]>     1
2 c     <data.frame [2 x 3]>     3
```